# TACACS with Juniper Devices

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-srx, aaa, tacacs

Can any one please help in configuring a TACACS+ server, along with configuration in Juniper devices?

- Ubuntu Server 14.04
- Juniper QFX5100 switch

Below are my configurations:

For the TACACS+ server:

```
#Encryption key
key = "test"

#Accounting Records

default authentication = file /etc/passwd

accounting syslog;

accounting file = var/log/tac_plus/tac_plus.acct

group = SU {
   default service = permit
   service = junos-exec {
     local-user-name = SU
   }
 }

user = admin_user {
 member =  SU
 login = file /etc/passwd
 }
```

For the Juniper devices:

```
set system authentication-order tacplus
set system authentication-order password
set system root-authentication encrypted-password "$1$reAOW7RO$wRFyLe1K.3FZFq7XWVw1"
set system tacplus-server 172.16.x.x secret "$9$.mz6pu1hyKBI"
set system tacplus-server 172.16.x.x source-address 172.16.x.x
set system accounting events login
set system accounting events change-log
set system accounting events interactive-commands
set system accounting destination tacplus server 172.16.1.229 secret "$9$Pf390SlMIE"
set system login class admin idle-timeout 30
set system login class admin permissions all
set system login user SU full-name local-user-name
set system login user SU uid 2002
set system login user SU class admin
```

Please help me, as I am stuck for the last 3 months. I have no clue which mistakes I am making. I am able to get the logs, but I am unable to authenticate users, which is very much important for me.

Comment: What version of JunOS are you using?  I think in the QFX line they changed the login classes, so you would use qfabric-admin instead of admin.  First, though, can you successfully login with a local user?

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I'm finding myself with a similar issue..